# Scala: What is the type of a function object that takes two parameter lists?

Tags: scala, types, implicit, higher-order-functions

Suppose I want to pass, as an argument to a higher-order function, a function object that takes two parameter lists. What is the type of such an object?

For example, this might be such an object:

```
object passMe extends <???> {
    def apply(x: Double)(implicit ctx: Context): String = . . .
}
```

What should I put after `extends`? Or how would I declare a function that would accept `passMe` as a parameter?

```
def foundation(xs: Seq[Double], oneOfThoseObjects: <???>)(implicit ctx: Context): Unit = {
  . . .
  xs.map(oneOfThoseObjects).toSet. . . .
}
```

My example uses an implicit parameter list, since that's mainly what I'm interested in, but it would still help to know how to declare a function with two explicit parameter lists. I haven't found anything yet in the Function1, Function2, ... series that suggests what such a declaration would look like.

Comment: what is the return type of the function?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I used `String` in the example.

Answer (score 2):

A function with two parameter lists can be modeled as a function that returns another function. This is a technique called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). For example, the addition function can be written like this:

```
scala> val add:Function1[Int,Function1[Int, Int]] = x => (y => x + y)
add: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

And called like this:

```
scala> add(1)(2)
res1: Int = 3
```

As you can see, the same type can be written both with `Function1` and with `=>` syntax.

Comment: Ah, thanks. In hindsight, I should have guessed, since `add(1)` is a one-parameter-list function. Do you know how to indicate that the parameter list is implicit?

Comment: I've tried to get this to work with an implicit parameter list, but I don't think it's possible. You could define a class with an `apply` method that has an implicit parameter list and then return an instance of this class form the `add` function, but there is no way to call the `apply` method without explicitly passing an argument.

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around in the REPL, I arrived at this:

```
(Double => (Context => String))
```

Which, in English, says, "Function taking a double and returning a function taking a Context and returning a String"

Thus, your `passMe` object would look something like this:

```
object passMe extends (Double => (Context => String)) {
  def apply(d: Double) = {
    def f(c: Context) = "...something..."
    f _
  }
}
```

However, because of the implicit parameter, this won't work, because with the implicit parameter, you end up with a type mismatch (you need a `scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString`).  So I eventually ended up with this:

```
object passMe extends (Double => scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) {
  def apply(d: Double) = {
    def f(implicit c: Context) = "...something..."
    f _
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I now I see that multiple parameter lists are just syntactic sugar for a function returning a function, which you've spelled out explicitly. Where does the `WrappedString` come from? Does that have something to do with persuading Scala to pass `ctx` to `oneOfThoseObjects` in `foundation`?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  The `WrappedString` seems to appear when you add the `implicit`.  I hope somebody can explain it to me, actually.